# How To perform Minus query like operation on Two Data Frames in Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have **two dataframes** and I have to perform **MINUS Query** to get only unique values of dataframe_1.
How can I perform it? Can I perform it using **merge** as I do not know common column to give inside *'on'* parameter.
Also I tried it using **Pandasql**, but got an error.

```
q1 = """SELECT * FROM df_1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM df_2;
"""

print(pandasql.sqldf(q1, locals()))
```

My DATAFRAMES:

```
       Last    First       Role  Salary
0  Thompson    Aaron  Developer   72000
1    Miller    James  Developer   68000
2    Bryant   Samuel     Tester   54000
3     Jones  Richard     Tester   56500


   

    Last      First    Role    Salary
0   Thompson  Aaron Developer   72000
1   Miller    James Developer   68000
2   Bryant   Samuel    Tester   54000
3   Nirmal  Ojjaswi   Analyst   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code snippet below, not very optimized but will solve your purpose:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'last' : ['Thompson', 'Miller', 'Bryant', 'Jones'], 
                            'first' : ['Aaron', 'James', 'Samuel', 'Richard'],
                            'role' : ['Developer', 'Developer', 'Tester', 'Tester'],
                            'salary' : [72000, 68000, 54000, 56500]}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'last' : ['Thompson', 'Miller', 'Bryant', 'Nirmal'], 
                            'first' : ['Aaron', 'James', 'Samuel', 'Ojjaswi'],
                            'role' : ['Developer', 'Developer', 'Tester', 'Analyst'],
                            'salary' : [72000, 68000, 54000, 0]})
```

Sample Input:

```py
df1.head()

       last    first       role  salary
0  Thompson    Aaron  Developer   72000
1    Miller    James  Developer   68000
2    Bryant   Samuel     Tester   54000
3     Jones  Richard     Tester   56500

df2.head()

       last    first       role  salary
0  Thompson    Aaron  Developer   72000
1    Miller    James  Developer   68000
2    Bryant   Samuel     Tester   54000
3    Nirmal  Ojjaswi    Analyst       0
```

```py
df1[~df1.fillna('').astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1).isin(df2.fillna('').astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1))]
```

Sample Output:

```
    last    first    role  salary
3  Jones  Richard  Tester   56500
```

```py
df2[~df2.fillna('').astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1).isin(df1.fillna('').astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1))]
```

Sample Output:

```
     last    first     role  salary
3  Nirmal  Ojjaswi  Analyst       0
```

Comment: It is giving me an empty dataframe.

Comment: This might be because you are trying to minus subset DF from the bigger one, therefore bigger one will have all the elements of smaller df and the output will be blank. Can you provide any sample input dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```py
df1:
       Last    First       Role  Salary
0  Thompson    Aaron  Developer   72000
1    Miller    James  Developer   68000
2    Bryant   Samuel     Tester   54000
3     Jones  Richard     Tester   56500
df2:
       Last    First       Role  Salary
0  Thompson    Aaron  Developer   72000
1    Miller    James  Developer   68000
2    Bryant   Samuel     Tester   54000
3    Nirmal  Ojjaswi    Analyst       0
```

Doing:

```py
df = df1[df1.ne(df2).all(axis=1)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
    Last    First    Role  Salary
3  Jones  Richard  Tester   56500
```

---

Given:

```py
df1:
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12
3     4    13
4     5    14
df2:
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12
```

Doing/Output:

```py
df = df1[df1.ne(df2).all(axis=1)]
print(df)

# Output:

   col1  col2
3     4    13
4     5    14
5     3    10
```